# How to search for values in Excel "table"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, libreoffice-calc

If I've for example this table:

```
a,6,10,22,35,46
b,2,7,11,23,44,78
c,2,10,15,16,32,66,98
d,7,8,10,11,23,25,30
e,23,24
```

Now I want to search for occurances of a certain value and returns the value of the first column of each corresponding row.

So `2` gives: `b,c`. And `23` gives `b,d,e`.

Like:

```
2,b,c
23,b,d,e
```

Is it possible to achieve this by using the VLOOPUP- or another function?

Thanks!

Comment: is the return in one cell? or multiple?

Comment: @ScottCraner What do you mean? I've edited the post, maybe that makes it a little clearer.

Comment: I would use INDEX\MATCH https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/

Comment: The way you have written your data in a Transposed fashion is really confusing. Just create a simple snippet screenshot next time please

Comment: @Rawrplus Transposed fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) solution, you can create your own function:

*just make sure to insert it into a new module*

```
Option Explicit

Public Function INCOLUMNS(ByVal value As String, ByVal searchrange As Range) As String

    Dim res As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Range

    For i = 1 To searchrange.Columns.Count
        Set temp = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(searchrange.Rows.Count, i)). _ 
                   Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then
            If res = "" Then
                res = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
            Else
                res = res & ", " & Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    INCOLUMNS = res
End Function
```

And then you can use it inside the `Worksheet` like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, and that the Column is consistent with `,` and no spacing, the formula that I made is the following:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",23,",A1)),"23,b,d,e",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",2,",A1)),"2,b,c","N/A"))
```

Assuming the `a,6,10,22,35,46` is in `A1`, you would for example paste this in `B1` and drag the formula down. This would get you the results that you are looking for in your example.

Answer I got with this formula:

[image: Results]

Documentation on `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH` formula: https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-contains

Hope this helps,

-Maykid

Comment: While i like your solution, I don't think this is what OP wanted (although how his question is formatted didn't help too much). I think it's supposed to return occurances of each number inside the column. eg. `23`is inside the column `B,D,E`

Comment: @Rawrplus Yes, search for occurance of a given value. So `23` appears in the rows starting with `b`, `c` and `d`.